# Mounted own filesystem instead of USB?

Tags: mount

I am completely unfamiliar with how *nix handles partitions, but I needed to get a file off of my USB drive so I followed an online [post](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=104774) that said you could mount a USB stick with:

```
sudo mount -t auto /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

So I did, but now `ls /mnt` returns the contents of my computer's /home/ directory, and I am afraid to unmount it.

How can I get out of this situation without compromising any data?

Where can I find an accessible explanation of how to mount a usb drive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evidently you have two hard drives in the machine, and you have a dedicated `/home` partition on the second one.

What's happened is `/dev/sdb1` (which is not your USB drive) is now mounted twice, once on `/home` and once on `/mnt`.  The only real risk in that is you now also have double the opportunities to, e.g., delete something accidentally.  If you are not in the habit of doing such things, then no worries.

> How can I get out of this situation without compromising any data?

Just `umount /mnt`.  If you get a "device busy" message, it's because a shell or file browser is open to that location -- change directory in those.

> Where can I find an accessible explanation of how to mount a usb drive?

Contemporary linux distributions (and I presume other *nix's) come out of the box with desktop environments that will do automounting, so most newbies don't have to worry much about this stuff.

If for some reason you aren't using an automounter, `man mount` is a good starting place.  Device nodes get assigned in order -- this is why `/dev/sdb1` turned out not to be the USB.  One way to get a clue about the proper device node would be to look at the various `sd` files in `/dev` without the stick in, then add it and look again.  If you already have two hard drives, plugging in another (including USB sticks) will probably yield **sdc**, and sdc1 would be the first partition.

Comment: Also, `mount` (without anything else) list all mount points, `fdisk -l` list all the devices and partitions.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the added explanation. It turns out I do have an auto-mounting system, though now it is upset. In nautilus, my USB drive shows up in gray, and says 'failed to mount,' though if I try to unmount it (in nautilus) it says 'writing data to device \n there is data that needs to be written to the device. Please do not remove the device.' Do you have any idea what it would be doing, and if I could remove the drive?

Comment: Actually, it was Thunar (Nautilus doesn't show the drive), but I can't seem to edit my last comment. I tried cosing all open windows.

Answer (score 1):

Because you've mounted it via a different location than that of `/home`, you should be able to unmount it without loss of data: `umount /mnt`. I assume you've not started any processes from /mnt. You can check for open files from that mount point with something like `lsof`.

Attempting to umount whilst files ARE open from /mnt will give you an error anyway:

```
umount: unmount of /mnt failed: Device busy
```

As to finding the correct device for the USB disk:

`sudo lshw -class disk`

should allow you to find the `/dev/sdX` device you require.